# Already defined in obj

Tags: c++

> 1. Error  LNK2005 "void __cdecl Command::addCommand(struct Command::Command)" (?addCommand@Command@@YAXU11@@Z) already defined in  main.cpp.obj   D:\Code\cpp\discord\DexunBot\MainBot\CMakeLists.txt  D:\Code\cpp\discord\DexunBot\MainBot\dexun_client.cpp.obj  1
> 2. Error  LNK2005 "void __cdecl CommandHandler::RegisterCommands(void)" (?RegisterCommands@CommandHandler@@YAXXZ) already defined in main.cpp.obj D:\Code\cpp\discord\DexunBot\MainBot\CMakeLists.txt D:\Code\cpp\discord\DexunBot\MainBot\dexun_client.cpp.obj   1
> 3. Error  LNK2005 "void __cdecl CommandHandler::CheckExecuteCommand(class DexunClientClass &,struct SleepyDiscord::Message)" (?CheckExecuteCommand@CommandHandler@@YAXAEAVDexunClientClass@@UMessage@SleepyDiscord@@@Z) already defined in main.cpp.obj   D:\Code\cpp\discord\DexunBot\MainBot\CMakeLists.txt D:\Code\cpp\discord\DexunBot\MainBot\dexun_client.cpp.obj   1
> 4. Error  LNK2005 "class std::unordered_map,class std::allocator >,struct Command::Command,struct std::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > const ,struct Command::Command> > > Command::all" (?all@Command@@3V?$unordered_map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@UCommand@3@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@UCommand@3@@std@@@2@@std@@A) already defined in main.cpp.obj D:\Code\cpp\discord\DexunBot\MainBot\CMakeLists.txt D:\Code\cpp\discord\DexunBot\MainBot\dexun_client.cpp.obj   1

When trying to compile my project I get some linker errors.

I've already tried to seperate my command.hpp into a command.cpp file also, but I would get errors like std::function doesn't exist or something similar.

````cpp
// command.hpp
class DexunClientClass;

namespace Command {
    using Verb = std::function<
        void(
            DexunClientClass&,
            SleepyDiscord::Message&,
            std::queue<std::string>&
            )
    >;

    struct Command {
        std::string name;
        std::vector<std::string> params;
        std::string description;
        Verb verb;
    };
    using MappedCommands = std::unordered_map<std::string, Command>;
    using MappedCommand = MappedCommands::value_type;
    MappedCommands all;
    void addCommand(Command command) {
        all.emplace(command.name, command);
    }
}

// command_handler.hpp
#include "sleepy_discord/sleepy_discord.h"

#include "commands/help_command.hpp"
#include "dexun_client.hpp"

namespace CommandHandler {
    void RegisterCommands() {
        HelpCommand helpCommand;
        helpCommand.registerHelpCommand();
    }

    void CheckExecuteCommand(DexunClientClass& client, SleepyDiscord::Message message) {
        client.sendMessage(message.channelID, "WFAWFWF");
    }
}

// dexun_client.hpp
#include "sleepy_discord/websocketpp_websocket.h"

class DexunClientClass : public SleepyDiscord::DiscordClient {
public:
    using SleepyDiscord::DiscordClient::DiscordClient;

    void onMessage(SleepyDiscord::Message message) override;
};

// dexun_client.cpp
#include "dexun_client.hpp"

#include "command.hpp"
#include "command_handler.hpp"

std::queue<std::string> split(const std::string& source) {
    std::stringstream ss(source);
    std::string item;
    std::queue<std::string> target;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, ' '))
        if (!item.empty())
            target.push(item);
    return target;
}

void DexunClientClass::onMessage(SleepyDiscord::Message message) {
    if (message.startsWith("dexun") || message.startsWith("dex")) {
        CommandHandler::CheckExecuteCommand(*this, message);

        std::queue<std::string> parameters = split(message.content);
        const std::string mention = "<@" + message.author.ID + ">";
        const std::string mentionNick = "<@!" + message.author.username + ">";
        if (
            //only allow if has more then 1 parameter 
            parameters.size() <= 1 &&
            //only allow if starts with a mention
            (parameters.front() != mention || parameters.front() != mentionNick)
            )
            return;

        //remove the parameters as we go
        parameters.pop();
        if (parameters.empty())
            return;

        //get command
        Command::MappedCommands::iterator foundCommand =
            Command::all.find(parameters.front());
        if (foundCommand == Command::all.end()) {
            sendMessage(message.channelID, "Error: Command not found");
            return;
        }
        parameters.pop();
        if (
            parameters.size() <
            foundCommand->second.params.size()
            ) {
            sendMessage(message.channelID, "Error: Too few parameters");
            return;
        }

        //call command
        foundCommand->second.verb(*this, message, parameters);
    }
}

// main.cpp
#include "dexun_client.hpp"
#include "command_handler.hpp"

int main() {
    DexunClientClass client("token", 2);

    CommandHandler::RegisterCommands();
    std::cout << "Registered Commands" << std::endl;

    client.run();
}```
````

Comment: In the name of the mighty [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), thou shalt not define in a header unless steps have been taken to prevent repetition. In the case of `Command::addCommand`, make the sucker `inline`

Comment: Ditto `CommandHandler::RegisterCommands` and `CommandHandler::CheckExecuteCommand`, but I suspect it might be better to define them in a cpp file. They look to be doing things that are better off left out of a header where they can slow down builds if you change them while developing.

Comment: Consider writing less code before compiling and testing. You find mistakes faster and are less likely to repeat them.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you aren't using header guards or pagma once. 2nd, you can easily fix "std::function doesn't exist" by including the standard function library.

Anyway, when including dexun_client.hpp, you'll also include sleepy_discord/websocketpp_websocket. So far no issue. But let's include command_handler, which also includes sleepy_discord/sleepy_discord commands/help_command and whatever that includes, and dexun_client. I don't see dexun_client.hpp with any header guards or other ways to stop it from being included more then once. However that didn't show up as an error so I'm going to guess command.hpp is also included in. help_command.hpp.

Also, I have a feeling you copied my code without any idea of how it works. However that made me realize that I wasn't using any header guards but if you take a look at https://github.com/yourWaifu/sleepy-discord/tree/develop/examples/sound-player. It didn't need any because it only has one header file and it's only included once.

Tl dr: I think it's because you are missing header guards not #pagma once.

Comment: I left the header guards out of the code. There are header guards. Next time I'll be sure to include them in my code examples. I've given up on the project, for now getting too busy with school.